# What is the best way to debug when a jquery post is not firing off an asp.net mvc controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, debugging, forms, post

I put a breakpoint on the controller action but it never fires.  Is there anyway to catch errors on a jquery post?

here is my jquery javascript code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#commitExerciseButton').live('click', function() {

            $.post($("#exerciseForm").attr('action'), $("#exerciseForm").serialize(), function(data) {

                $("#exercise").html("<h1>Exercise Added</h1>");
                $("#tabs-2").html(data);

            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

### EDIT:

I figured out the issue.. i had to do:

**$("#exerciseForm Form").serialize()** instead of **$("#exerciseForm").serialize()**

Comment: If you can post an example code it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a ORM as well? just asking because I recently encountered such a situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you can use `$.ajax` instead you can define an eror callback and see what is returning, also a tool like firebug for firefox are very usefull for seeing what is being posted, here is a [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) showing the ajax call and error callback

Answer (score 0):

That may be a number of reasons cause that the action not even be fired in an asp.net mvc project. Does your action accepts POST request only? Does the javascript invocation make the correct parameters for your action? Does your action requires an anti-forgery token? There is a [tool](http://hg.digideas.com/mvc.apiexplorer/) can helps you to check that or just check all details carefully by eyes.